# Let ABC be a triangle with AB = 16. Let M and N be the midpoints of the medians AA1 and BB1. Find MN

Tags: geometry

Tried to solve using similar triangles but am falling short.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you solve it for an equilateral triangle?

Comment: I think the answer is $\;|MN|=4\;$ , but I'll try to find a decent diagram to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at :
[image]

The lower central point is $\;A_1\;$ and the right central one is $\;B_1\;$ . On $\;AA_1\;$, above the central point ( let's call it $\;Q\,$) we have $\;M\;$ , and on $\;BB_1\;$, to the left of $\;Q\;$ we have $\;N\:$ .

Using the medians theorem, we have that

$$|QM|=|QA|-|MA|=\frac23|AA_1|-\frac12|AA_1|=\frac16|AA_1|$$

and likewise

$$|QN|=\frac16|BB_1|$$

We thus have that

$$\frac{|QA_1|}{|QM|}=\frac{\frac13|AA_1|}{\frac16|AA_1|}=2$$

and likewise

$$\frac{|QB_1|}{|QN|}=\frac{\frac13|BB_1|}{\frac16|BB_1|}=2$$

so by SAS, we have the similar triangles $\;\Delta QMN\sim \Delta QA_1B_1\;$ , from where we get

$$\frac8{|MN|}=\frac{|A_1B_1|}{|MN|}=\frac{|QB_1|}{|QN|}=2\implies |MN|=4$$

( Can you see why $\;|A_1B_1|=8\;$?)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $C_1$ be the midpoint of $AB$.

$B_1,M,C_1$ are the midpoints of $A$ to collinear $C, A_1, B$ respectively, and so $B_1, M, C_1$ are collinear and is $C, A_1, B$ scaled by half, by mid-point theorem. Notably, $M$ is the mid-point of $B_1C_1$.

Similarly, $A_1, N, C_1$ are collinear and is $C, B_1, A$ scaled by half. $N$ is the mid-point of $A_1C_1$.

By mid-point theorem, $2MN = B_1A_1$ and $2B_1A_1 = AB = 16$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Given this diagram, it should be pretty clear how to apply Thales' theorem.
The medians $AA_1,BB_1$ intersect at the centroid $G$, with $\frac{AG}{GA_1}=\frac{BG}{GB_1}=2$.
By dividing each median into six equal segments, it follows that the distance between the midpoint of $AA_1$ and the midpoint of $BB_1$ is one fourth of the length of $AB$.